# Php put a space in front of capitals in a string (Regex)

Tags: php, regex

I have a number of strings which contain words which are bunched together and I need to seperate them up.

For example
ThisWasCool - This Was Cool
MyHomeIsHere - My Home Is Here

Im slowly getting my head around regular expressions and I believe to do this I should use preg_replace. My problem is putting together the expression to find the match.

I have only got this far

```
   preg_replace('~^[A-Z]~', " ", $string)
```

Each string contains a lot of words, but ONLY the first word contains bunched words so using my example above a string would be
"ThisWasCool to visit you again" - "This Was Cool to visit you again"

I have told it to start at the beginning, and look for capitals, but what I dont know how to do is 
- restrict it only to the first word of each string
- how to reuse the capital letter in the replace part after the space

Comment: "\n" for replacement. Did you mean space or newline?

Comment: doh its late here I did mean space, normally I would just put " ", but thats probably wrong!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

#### Problem

1. Your regex `'~^[A-Z]~'` will match only the first capital letter. Check out [Meta Characters](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) in the [Pattern Syntax](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) for more information.
2. Your replacement is a newline character `'\n'` and not a space.

#### Solution

Use this code:

```
$String = 'ThisWasCool';
$Words = preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', $String);
```

The `(?<!\ )` is an [assertion](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) that will make sure we don't add a space before a capital letter that already has a space before it.

Comment: How you can skip the space for the first capital letter?

Comment: I've got it: preg_replace('/(?<! )(?<!^)[A-Z]/',' $0', $String);

Comment: And, if you need one that doesn't seperate sequential capitals (for example, BusinessUnitID should be Business Unit ID, not Business Unit I D), then you can use /(?<! )(?<!^)(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]/

Answer (score 15):

```
$string = preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', ' $0', $string);
```

Maybe run the result through [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) after.

```
$string = ltrim(preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', ' $0', $string));
```

Comment: Thanks I guess the / are delimiters, is there a way to restrict it to only working on the first word? The data is coming from a csv so the first word is wrapped in " "?

Comment: Yes, there is. I suggested using ltrim to remove the space, but you could also do it in the expression with: /\B[A-Z]/

Answer (score 3):

Here's my .02c, this version will only act on the first word, and will preserve sequences of uppercase letters (BMW).

```
$str = "CheckOutMyBMW I bought it yesterday";
$parts = explode(' ', $str);
$parts[0] = preg_replace('~([a-z])([A-Z])~', '\\1 \\2', $parts[0]);
$newstr = implode(' ', $parts);
echo $newstr;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not proficient with regular expression but I would suggest something like the following code:

```
$string="ThisWasCool to visit you again";
$temp = explode(' ',$string, 2);
$temp[0] = preg_replace('/(.)([A-Z])/','$1 $2', $temp[0]);
$string = join(' ',$temp);
```

Looking at SirLancelot code I've got a second solution. Still I prefer the explode solution as you stated that your target it is only the first word of the string.

```
$string="ThisWasCool to visit you again";
$temp = explode(' ',$string, 2);
$temp[0] = preg_replace('/(?<!^)([A-Z])/',' $0', $temp[0]);
$string = join(' ',$temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the code above to act on all words

```
$str = "CheckOutMyBMW I bought itYesterday";
$parts = explode(' ', $str);
$parts2 = array();
foreach($parts as $key => $part){
    $parts2[$key] = preg_replace('~([a-z])([A-Z])~', '\\1 \\2', $part); 
}
$newstr = implode(' ', $parts2);
echo $newstr;
```

// Check Out My BMW I bought it Yesterday