# Cleaning up a string with punctuation mistakes and missing spaces

Tags: php, regex, string, punctuation

**Hi, I have the following string:**

---

TheLion is walking(proudly) through theJungle,but he misses hisTeddy.1very sad day!It is VegeterianDay,too. How can we help him?Maybe withBambi&a good song! Or with bread & butter;What do you think:agree?

I need this:

The Lion is walking (proudly) through the Jungle, but he misses his Teddy. 1 very sad day! It is Vegeterian Day, too. How can we help him? Maybe with Bambi & a good song! Or with bread & butter; What do you think: agree?

---

### *1very and 1Very should be treated the same way.*

I've tried this:

```
<?php
$string="TheLion is walking(proudly) through theJungle,but he misses hisTeddy.1very sad day!It is VegeterianDay,too. How can we help him?Maybe withBambi&a good song! Or with bread & butter;What do you think:agree?";
echo trim(preg_replace_callback('~\b\'\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\s*(\p{P}+)\s*~u', function($m) {
    return preg_replace('~\X(?=\X)~u', '$0 ', $m[1]) . ' ';
}, $string)); 
?>
```

Result:

TheLion is walking( proudly) through theJungle, but he misses hisTeddy. 1very sad day! It is VegeterianDay, too. How can we help him? Maybe withBambi& a good song! Or with bread& butter; What do you think: agree?

---

**Thanks a lot**

Comment: Time for the famous "What have you tried"?

Comment: ok sorry. i will add that in a second. Don´t hate :D

Comment: Maybe this can help you a bit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089613/php-put-a-space-in-front-of-capitals-in-a-string-regex and I recommend regex101.com to testing it out

Comment: `1 very sad day!` it sure is... When you use numbers in written text as words 15 baby kittens die.

Comment: It could be also | Height:10meters | but it should be | Height: 10 meters | I think there are enough baby kittens out there :O

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/9tIORf/1

Comment: Or like https://regex101.com/r/eJpu9T/1

Comment: @Camilo It helped me much... Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Wiktor Stribiżew and The fourth bird... You saved my day. One worked a little better for me. I will publish my result!

Comment: @Thefourthbird i´ve got a last question: i should have written | walking(proudly)through | instead of | walking(proudly) through | How can i achieve this | walking (proudly)through | too?

Comment: Try adding `)` to the character class https://regex101.com/r/eJpu9T/2

Comment: @Thefourthbird ok got it - thank you!

Comment: @Thefourthbird i found another "bug". How to exclude something like | 2,5cm | ? Now it becomes 2, 5 cm | should be | 2,5 cm |

Comment: You might skip fail the digit comma digit values https://regex101.com/r/eJpu9T/3 Note that all these extra requirements can lead to more edge cases.

Comment: works great! Appreciate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Thefourthbird

```
<?php
$str = "TheLion is walking(proudly) through theJungle,but he misses hisTeddy.1very sad day!It is VegeterianDay,too. How can we help him?Maybe withBambi&a good song! Or with bread & butter;What do you think:agree?";
$re = '/\b(?=[(][A-Za-z])|(?<=[,.!;:?)])\b|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[a-z]&)|(?=&[a-z])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])/m';
$subst = ' ';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
?>
```

result:

The Lion is walking (proudly) through the Jungle, but he misses his Teddy. 1 very sad day! It is Vegeterian Day, too. How can we help him? Maybe with Bambi & a good song! Or with bread & butter; What do you think: agree?

**Have a nice weekend!**