# How to add space in PHP string only between full CamelCase words skipping single uppercase letters intact?

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to add spaces in string like this:
**IMACSuperSeriousLabelDCN**

to have output like:

**IMAC Super Serious Label DCN**

Currently I have managed to use this code in PHP:

```
$label = preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', $field);
```

However it doesn't consider skipping single uppercase letters so I get:
**I M A C Super Serious Label D C N**

How can I skip inserting space between uppercase letters but placing a space before uppercase letter followed by lowercase one and also after lowercase letter occurs couple of uppercase letters (end of example string?

Comment: So, you found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089681/3832970) but it does not work for you.

Comment: Just FYI: with regex, it is too hard to deal with single letter captitalized words like `I` or `A` (e.g. `IMACASuperSeriousLabelDCN` => `IMAC A Super Serious Label DCN`)

Comment: I've checked the link and yes I've been using it however my case was more advanced than the ones shown in answers.
Fortunately I should not have the cases with A and I letters as you posted :)

Comment: See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/xi6BsX/1) based on the edited linked solution. Another solution from that thread is [also working](https://regex101.com/r/xi6BsX/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be using 2 capturing groups and an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) using a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) to share the same capturing groups

```
(?|([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])|([a-z])([A-Z]))
```

- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `([A-Z])` Capture group 1, match A-Z
  - `([A-Z][a-z])` Capture group 2
  - `|` Or
  - `([a-z])` Capture group 1, match a-z
  - `([A-Z])` Capture group 2, match A-Z
- `)` Close branch reset group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mvfIFG/1)

In the replacement use

```
$1 $2
```

Output

```
IMAC Super Serious Label DCN
```

Comment: You PHP-obfuscated a usual lookaround solution for this - `(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Aha, you are right...:) you should post it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this also works and by still using " $0" as replacement!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to check for each upper-case character whether the preceding character is lower-case, or the next character is lower-case, and if it is, insert a space beforehand:

```
$field = "IMACSuperSeriousLabelDCN";
$label = preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]|[A-Z](?=[a-z])/', ' $0', $field);
echo $label . "\n";
```

Output:

```
IMAC Super Serious Label DCN
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vg405)